# bash - how to delete every nth line of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have this

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
```

My aim is to have

```
line1
line3
line4
line6
line7
line9
line10
line12
line13
line15
```

I tried the code below this but it is not doing what I want. i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
awk 'NR == 1 || NR % 3 != 0' file
```

Any clues on the why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had the right idea using `% 3` - just [off by one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) since you want to remove starting at line 2 rather than 3. The test for `NR == 1` is superfluous, falling within the modulus test, but it wasn't causing any trouble:

```
$ awk '(NR+1) % 3' file
line1
line3
line4
line6
line7
line9
line10
line12
line13
line15
```

Comment: Crazy how the simplest answers to easy questions get more upvotes than detailed answers to complex problems.

Comment: @JID I really can't disagree. But, let's just take it as karma for the effort put into the complex, yet unsung, problems.

Comment: Yep, and i wasn't saying that nastily, I just feel bad for the poster when I see a really well thought out answer with 1 vote :(

Answer (score 8):

You can just use GNU sed:

```
 sed -i '2~3d' test.txt
```

You can also remove the `-i` in case you would not want to save the result.

---

Extract for sed man page:

> first~step
> Match  every  step'th  line starting with line first.  For example, `sed -n 1~2p` will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address `2~5` will match every fifth line,
> starting with the second.

Comment: Nice alternative, but note that this only works in _GNU_ `sed` (and given that the OP didn't ask for _in-place_ updating, I suggest removing the `-i`).

Comment: you're right, i forgot to say it was a GNU extension to sed. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Azatik1000 I added the reference to the man page

Answer (score 3):

To ignore the lines like in your example output, use

```
awk 'NR % 3 != 2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
awk '(NR+1)%3' file
line1
line3
line4
line6
line7
line9
line10
line12
line13
line15
```

This will skip every 3rd line starting from line #2. So line # 2, 5, 8, 11, 14 will be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it with portable `sed`.

To delete every 3rd line:

```
sed 'n; n; d' infile
```

To delete every 3rd line, starting with line 2:

```
sed '1n; 2d; n; n; d' infile
```

Output:

```
line1
line3
line4
line6
line7
line9
line10
line12
line13
line15
```